# Moving a relevant question to J.SE

Tags: discussion, migration

How do we move a question like this one: [What are the “household gods” Rachel stole from Laban?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/5471) to our site where it might be more relevant?

Comment: Original question has now been migrated to Biblical Hermeneutics, where it is more at home.

Answer (score 3):

Re-ask it here from a this-site perspective if you are interested in obtaining an answer from a this-site perspective. [There's nothing wrong with having the same question in two places if it's asked to get answers from the respective perspectives<sup>[1]</sup> of the two sites' users.](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/54)

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Say *that* ten times fast.

Comment: _that_ _that_ _that_ _that_ _that_ _that_ _that_ _that_ _that_ _that_ hmmmmmmm